# SQL- Query to determine if any NULLS in a column

Tags: sql

I need to create a query to determine if any records in a table contain NULLS in the EXPORTED column. If so then it will execute a stored procedure. I tried searching and I could not find anything that queries just one specific column. Below is an example of my table.

```
+--------+-----------+----------+
| SAMPLE |   DATE    | EXPORTED |
+--------+-----------+----------+
| S1234  | 9/17/2019 | NULL     |
| S1435  | 9/17/2019 | NULL     |
| S1536  | 9/17/2019 | YES      |
+--------+-----------+----------+
```

Comment: Hint: `count(*)` counts all rows, `count(EXPORTED)` counts non-null's.

Comment: @jarlh both COUNT(*) and COUNT(EXPORTED) return the same number of rows, even though there are a few dozen NULLS.

Comment: Strange. Do you store the string 'NULL'?

Comment: Anyway, simply do `select count(*) from tablename where exported is null`.

Comment: @jarlh Opps, I was querying the wrong table. Looks good. Thanks.